# how can JAXB generate such an element <_ /> with my object?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Here is my object:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"profile", "request", "filter"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "SubmitXml")
public class SubmitXml {
    @XmlElement(name = "Profile")
    protected String profile;
    @XmlElement(name = "Request")
    protected SubmitXml.Request request;
    @XmlElement(name = "Filter")
    protected SubmitXml.Filter filter;

    public String getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }

    public void setProfile(String value) {
        this.profile = value;
    }

    public SubmitXml.Request getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    public void setRequest(SubmitXml.Request value) {
        this.request = value;
    }

    public SubmitXml.Filter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    public void setFilter(SubmitXml.Filter value) {
        this.filter = value;
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
            "any"
    })
    public static class Filter {

        @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
        protected Object any;

        public Object getAny() {
            return any;
        }

        public void setAny(Object value) {
            this.any = value;
        }
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
            "any"
    })
    public static class Request {

        @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
        @XmlElementRefs({
                @XmlElementRef(name = "AirAvailability", type = AirAvailability.class)
        })
        protected Object any;

        public Object getAny() {
            return any;
        }

        public void setAny(Object value) {
            this.any = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and I want to marshal it into this xml below:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<soap:Envelope>
    <soap:Body><SubmitXml>
        <Profile>DynGalileoProd_7OQ7</Profile>
        <Request>
            <AirAvailability_12 xmlns=\"\">
                <AirAvailMods>
                    <GenAvail>
                        <NumSeats>2</NumSeats>
                        <Class>Y</Class>
                        <StartDt>20151201</StartDt>
                        <StartPt>TPE</StartPt>
                        <EndPt>HKG</EndPt>
                        <StartTm><![CDATA[ ]]></StartTm>
                    </GenAvail>
                </AirAvailMods>
            </AirAvailability_12>
        </Request>
        <Filter><_ /></Filter>
    </SubmitXml>
</soap:Body>
```

the problem is how can I generate such an element like `<_ />` at element Filter?

another question is how can I generate element text like `<![CDATA []]>` at element `<StartTm>`? The characters `<` and `>` are always changed into `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Comment: another question is how can I generate element text like at element StartTm? the charater '<' and '>' always be changed into '&lt;' and '&gt;'

Answer (score 0):

With this method:

```
<T> JAXBElement<T> wrap( String ns, String tag, T o ){
    QName qtag = new QName( ns, tag );
    Class<?> clazz = o.getClass();
    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    JAXBElement<T> jbe = new JAXBElement( qtag, clazz, o );
    return jbe;
}
```

it is possible to do

```
Filter filter = new Filter();
String s = "";
filter.setAny( wrap( "", "_", s ) );
```

and this will create

```
 <Filter><_></_></Filter>
```

and since `<_/>` is, by definition, the same as `<_></_>`, you have what you want.

Your second request cannot fulfilled without writing your own XML writer. However, it is definitely unnecessary to do so. Using or not using `<![CDATA []]>` is a matter of convenience when editing XML manually. If the XML writer escapes `<` and `>` properly, there is no reason why CDATA should be used.